# How to set up android Layout to Look like a page. Picture Included

Tags: android, layout

I would like to set up an page in android to have this kind of [page](http://i.imgur.com/Ln1d3IR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selvin is right. This looks like a [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)

[The design docs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#)